# What happens to the collaborator if the creator deletes files for repo?

Tags: angular, typescript, git, github

I'm new to Github, and have an assignment where I have to collaborate with a classmate to add code to an existing website using Angular/TypeScript.

First, we had to separately initialize the repo by cloning it and then following some steps to correctly open up a DevContainer. Then, one team member creates the team by creating a team name (based on assigned numbers for each teammate), which will then accept the assignment on behalf of both students. Then, the other member of the team will accept the assignment as well. We then follow several steps in the terminal to add the team remote the the repository.

I think I did something wrong in the last few steps, because I keep getting errors in module imports among other things, and every time I go to office hours, one thing will get fixed, but a whole other list of problems will occur. I want to just start fresh and restart the entire process again, but I was wondering if there's a specific process I'd have to go through to do this. Would it be possible to just delete the container/files, and then go through the process as if it were my first time? Would it affect my teammate's access to the repo? Also, If I do delete those files and start over, would I still be the creator of the repo, or would permissions transfer over to my teammate? Is there a specific way to go about this?
Thank you!

The first issue was that the commands I was given on the assignment to run weren't working, and by going to office hours, I learned that Angular made 2 copies of the files that were changed, so she deleted the the changes. After this, the commands still didn't work, and I'm not exactly sure what I did later on, but I believe I tried running some other commands to try and fix the issue, and it did not work. It started a whole process of going back and forth with office hours, and I'm convinced that I did something that completely messed everything up.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Please be specific to git as the question is meant to be for. If you just want to undo local uncommitted changes, do `git checkout .` If files in remote are deleted, they will be removed from your local in next `git pull` . You can anyway go back to any past commit state if you want as long as it is in git log history.

Comment: The changes have been committed already, but I just want to undo all the commands that were used to set up the assignment so I can redo everything from the beginning. How do I know if the commits are in my git log history?